# Android IntentFilter performance

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to refresh a specific row in a ListView (a custom class) when something happens in the ListView fragment or other (nested) fragment.

I'm currently using this pattern (`News` is a custom class that `NewsView` is displaying):

- `NewsView` constructor:

  - registers BroadcastReceiver with IntentFilter for example `"UPDATE_NEWS_ITEM"`
  - in the onReceive I deserialize the `News` item and compare item ID
- action happens somewhere

  - I create Intent("UPDATE_NEWS_ITEM"), and add `News` item as Serializable Extra.

This means that each and every `NewsView` has to deserialize the `News` from the Intent and therefore this approach has a bit of an overhead.

On the other hand, I could register a broadcast receiver for each `NewsView` with IntentFilter like `"UPDATE_NEWS_ITEM_154"`, where 154 is the ID of the item. Then the broadcast intent would reach only one receiver and it seems more effective.

Is there any downside to registering so many broadcast receivers? Or Android will happily cope with potentially hundred of them?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use an `Interface` between the receiver and the list view class, or create an instance of the receiver directly in the class and use `registerReceiver` and `unregisterReceiver`?

Comment: I was simplifying things, there are multiple classes that display `News` and multiple classes that generate refresh, so I think not.

Comment: Surely implementing a call back listener in all of those classes is no more work than receiving an intent?  Without knowing your architecture, then you could create a base class Activity with the listener then inherit from that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are broadcasting only within your application, consider using intents through `LocalBroadcastManager` instead of broadcasting intents with an intent-filter in your manifest.

As far as I know those translate directly to function calls and do not pass through the OS queues.

More about [LocalBroadcastManager here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)